# Why my CLLocation information doesnt appear?

Tags: swift

I am making a app that appears with longitude, latitude, altitude and speed.

Whenever I run the app:
1. No location data shows in the Labels | 2. I get this error message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
@IBOutlet weak var longitude: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var latitude: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var altitude: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var speed: UILabel!

var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
var startLocation: CLLocation!

@IBAction func reset(sender: AnyObject) {
    startLocation = nil
}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    var latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]

    latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    longitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    altitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.altitude)


    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = latestLocation as! CLLocation
    }

    var distanceBetween: CLLocationDistance =
    latestLocation.distanceFromLocation(startLocation)

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

}
```

Then...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Location
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    startLocation = nil


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```

Comment: tl;dr

Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Declearing `startLocation` as an implicitly unwrapped optional is quite risky here, since it is not intended to be always != nil.

Try defining it as an optional:

```
var startLocation: CLLocation?
```

and change the resto of your code accordingly making the appropriate checks where needed.

As an example, when you calculate the distance:

```
if let startLocation = startLocation {
       var distanceBetween: CLLocationDistance =
       latestLocation.distanceFromLocation(startLocation)
}
```

Maybe somewhere else in your code you access `startLocation` when it might be `nil`

Since the nil exception occurs when you try to set the latitude label text, at first I would check if that label is correctly hooked up via Interface Builder. Is the little bullet on the left of its declaration coloured? Anyway you can put a breakpoint before that line of code and than check for what is nil and should not.

Comment: The error is coming up on the latitude.text line. In general, no results are coming up. Please help on how to fix this. @Matteo_Piombo